# Storing multiple values in one field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a script that will insert a value in a cell, in my database. That cell will contain 4 values total. It should look like this: 0;0;0;0 (Each '0', represents a value)

How can I insert example value 100, at the place where '0' number 3 is, so it will look like this:

0;0;100;0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you inserting serialized data into MySQL? (ie: why don't you have 4 columns instead of one?)

Comment: Are race conditions a possibility?

Comment: please please please do not do this.  flatten your data into 4 columns, or create a auxilliary table!  It's faster and easier.

Comment: But then what if I need 20 values, or 30 values stored. Should I just create 20/30 columns for that?

Comment: The answer is "it depends." If they are very sparse (ie: a lot of NULLs), then you might want to consider serializing. If not, create the 20/30 columns (you can use an auxiliary table like David suggests).

Comment: @Oliver what you are describing sounds like records not columns...  your data should be designed relationally to minimize repeating patters in your columns, maybe if you gave us more specifics on the data you're using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into `serialize()` and `unserialize()`

```
$array = array(0,20,103,330);
$string = serialize($array); // store this in db
```

then get the string from db:

```
$array = unserialize($string);
```

access/update values with the array and re-store in db

Or if you are stuck with the format:

```
$string = '0;0;100;0'; // coming from db
$array = explode(';' , $string);
$array[2] = 100;
$string = implode(';' , $array);
```

Comment: It'd be far easier to just have 4 columns instead and do the updates directly in the DB.

Comment: What @Marc suggests should be your first and foremost preference.

Comment: this is like patching a ship hull with duct tape, at some point it will come back to haunt you.

Answer (score 2):

This is bad database design and breaks the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Domains_and_values) of database design.

I would recommend re-thinking your schema and data architecture.

Maybe break them out into individual columns.

Your data should be designed relationally to minimize repeating patterns in your columns (see link above)

I can almost guarantee you that there **is** a better way...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    // original string of values seperated by colon
    $string = "0;0;0;0";

    // create array of values by splitting at colons
    $vals = preg_split('/;/', $string);

    // modify the value of any elements in your array
    $vals[2] = 100;

    // glue your array of values together with semicolons at the joins
    $string = implode(';',$vals);

    // check the value has been changed coreectly
    echo $string;

?>
```

Comment: technically correct, but this implies OP needs to do a select, then some processing, then an update instead of just having 4 columns, and doing a simple update...  also race condition, if two threads try to update different columns at once they may overwrite each other.